# Направление движения транспорта от двух координатных точек (азимут)

Tags: c++, node.js

Друзья, стоит следующая задача:

необходимо отображать направление движения транспортного средства (поворачивать "носик" иконки в нужном направлении). Все мы это видели в сервисах с ГИС (яндекс.карты, 2гис).

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из входных данных мы имеет ТОЛЬКО координаты перемещения ТС.

**Соответственно необходимо из двух точек с координатами (широта, долгота) вычислить азимут (в градусах).**

Использовал сервис: https://www.sas.com.ru/wp/ru/kalkuljator-azimuta-rasstojanija/, который считает всё это дело через формулу гаверсинусов:
θ = atan2 [(sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ₂), (cos φ₁ ⋅ sin φ₂ − sin φ₁ ⋅ cos φ₂ ⋅ cos Δλ)], но ничего не сходилось со значениями.

Просьба подсказать в этом вопросе. Желательно так, чтоб можно было посчитать на примитивном калькуляторе с математическими функциями.

Answer (score 0):

Берете две точки в маршруте, предыдущую и текущую. Переводите и ту и другую из широты/долготы в экранные координаты (вы же как-то сам кружочек рисуете).

Потом `std::atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)`, где `[x1,y1]` и `[x2,y2]` - это первая и вторая точки в экранных координатах.

Comment: а если посмотреть с южного полюса? Азимут == строго север.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Тьфу, там широта и долгота... Добавил приписку, что нужно перевести в экранные координаты. *"Азимут == строго север"* Википедия говорит, что обычно от севера, но в общем случае может быть от любого направления. Имхо, делать так, чтобы угол 0 смотрел в сторону -Y - неудобно, удобнее, когда угол в родном формате функции atan2. Но пересчитать - легко.